# boost::asio::deadline_timer causes "a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression" error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I´m trying to use boost 1.54.0 on Windows and got some problems with asio::deadline_timer.

Here´s my (quite simple) code:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using boost::asio::deadline_timer;

int main() {  
    deadline_timer timeout;
}
```

When I try to compile this snippet using gcc 4.7 (cygwin) the following errors occur:

```
g++ -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -D_WIN32_WINNT "-IC:\\dev\\lib\\boost_1_54_0" "-IC:\\dev\\workspace-cpp\\ts_core\\src" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\main.o" "..\\src\\main.cpp" 
In file included from C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_tss_ptr.ipp:24:0,
                 from C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:77,
                 from C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/detail/tss_ptr.hpp:27,
                 from C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/detail/call_stack.hpp:20,
                 from C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/impl/handler_alloc_hook.ipp:19,
                 from C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/handler_alloc_hook.hpp:80,
                 from C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp:21,
                 from C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:19,
                 from C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/detail/wrapped_handler.hpp:18,
                 from C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:25,
                 from C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from ..\src\main.cpp:8:
C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:77:17: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:130:15: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:135:19: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:149:23: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
C:\dev\lib\boost_1_54_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:163:15: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
..\src\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
..\src\main.cpp:24:17: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer<boost::posix_time::ptime>::basic_deadline_timer()'
```

I spent some time on research and added "-D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -D_WIN32_WINNT", but without success.
The problem seems to be the line "#include " which is line 8 in main.cpp

Comment: Your error message shows the problem on line eight but your example code has only six lines. What else is going on in your code?

Answer (score 3):

boost::asio::deadline_timer does not have default empty constructor.
you should use:

```
boost::asio::io_service _iosvc;
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(_iosvc);
```

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be the include itselt - I tried your code, but it still shows the error occuring in line 8 (which is the line "#include <boost/asio.hpp>")

Answer (score 2):

It appears there is something wrong with the build configuration. The lines you mention all are calls to a `BOOST_ASIO_WIN_OR_POSIX` macro which is the switch between calls to posix and native win implementation details. It seems your configuration somehow messes that up, includes the wrong headers and/or expands the macro wrong. The macro definition basically reads like this:

```
#if defined(BOOST_ASIO_WINDOWS) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
# define BOOST_ASIO_WIN_OR_POSIX(e_win, e_posix) e_win
#else
# define BOOST_ASIO_WIN_OR_POSIX(e_win, e_posix) e_posix
#endif
```

First question therefore: is `__CYGWIN__` defined during your build?

Comment: I added -D__CYGWIN__ to my g++ call. Still same problem... Any suggestions?

Comment: The first thing I'd do is just include that header in question into a fresh empty main.cpp and compile it (and hope the error still appears). Narrow down the error. Maybe eben look at the preprocessor output. Make copies of the boost headers in question, strip anything unneeded. Dig into the dirt ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This rings a bell for me; I think I had to work around the same problem once.  I believe that some of the error codes that ASIO uses are not specified in certain versions of Windows.  Try using the following:

```
-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501
```

This targets the build to a minimum of Windows XP (I believe).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it seems to be a problem of cygwin-gcc and building DLLs.

After I got some more very strange errors using boost, cygwin/gcc and eclipse (e.g. dynamic_pointer_cast not terminating, causing endless loop) I switched to VisualStudio '12 and everything worked like a charm...